# .Net putting \ where they dont belong

Tags: .net, json, api

I need help, I am just trying to get data from SQL and convert it to json but .NET keeps putting \'s everywhere :O
These are some of the methods I tried to use but I keep getting the same output.

```
SqlConnection Connection;

DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("exec getAllItems '%'", Connection);
Connection.Open();
dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
Connection.Close();

DataTable data = dataSet.Tables[0];

itemCount = data.Rows.Count;


string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataSet, Formatting.Indented);


string builtJson = DataTableToJSONWithJSONNet(data);
return json ;
```

---

```
public string DataTableToJSONWithJSONNet(DataTable table)
        {
            string JSONString = string.Empty;
            JSONString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(table);
            return JSONString;
        }


public string DataTableToJSONWithJavaScriptSerializer(DataTable table)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        List<Dictionary<string, object>> parentRow = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        Dictionary<string, object> childRow;
        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            childRow = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
            {
                childRow.Add(col.ColumnName, row[col]);
            }
            parentRow.Add(childRow);
        }
        return jsSerializer.Serialize(parentRow);
    }
    public string DataTableToJSONWithStringBuilder(DataTable table)
    {
        var JSONString = new StringBuilder();
        if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            JSONString.Append("[");
            for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                JSONString.Append("{");
                for (int j = 0; j < table.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (j < table.Columns.Count - 1)
                    {
                        JSONString.Append("\"" + table.Columns[j].ColumnName.ToString() + "\":" + "\"" + table.Rows[i][j].ToString() + "\",");
                    }
                    else if (j == table.Columns.Count - 1)
                    {
                        JSONString.Append("\"" + table.Columns[j].ColumnName.ToString() + "\":" + "\"" + table.Rows[i][j].ToString() + "\"");
                    }
                }
                if (i == table.Rows.Count - 1)
                {
                    JSONString.Append("}");
                }
                else
                {
                    JSONString.Append("},");
                }
            }
            JSONString.Append("]");
        }
        return JSONString.ToString();
    }
Returned Data
```

*"{\r\n  \"Table\": [\r\n    {\r\n      \"itemName\": \"PORC : SCARITA \",\r\n      \"itemCode\": \"11NAH     \",\r\n      \"Available_stock\": 48.80000000,\r\n      \"pA\": null,\r\n      \"pA_cutva\": null,\r\n      \"pB\": null,\r\n      \"pB_cutva\": null,\r\n      \"pC\": null,\r\n      \"pC_cutva\": null,\r\n      \"unit\": \"KG \",\r\n      \"item_class\": \"MARFURI        \",\r\n      \"item_group\": \"PRODUSE  \",\r\n      \"meat_type\": \"PORC \",\r\n      \"cotatva\": 0.090000,\r\n      \"min_qty_order\": null,\r\n      \"obsart\": 3,\r\n      \"pret_stand\": null,\r\n      \"pret_stand_cuTVA\": null,\r\n      \"Physical_stock\": 24.80000000,\r\n      \"OnTheRoad_stock\": 24.00000000\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"itemName\": \"PORC : CONGELAT BLOC\",\r\n      \"itemCode\": \"111CBL      \",\r\n      \"Available_stock\": 129.50000000,\r\n      \"pA\": 5.30000000,\r\n      \"pA_cutva\": 5.78000000,\r\n      \"pB\": 5.30000000,\r\n      \"pB_cutva\": 5.77700000,\r\n      \"pC\": null,\r\n      \"pC_cutva\": null,\r\n      \"unit\": \"KG \",\r\n      \"item_class\": \"MARFURI        \",\r\n      \"item_group\": \"PRODUSE CARNE  \",\r\n      \"meat_type\": \"PORC \",\r\n      \"cotatva\": 0.090000,\r\n      \"min_qty_order\": null,\r\n      \"obsart\": 2,\r\n      \"pret_stand\": null,\r\n      \"pret_stand_cuTVA\": null,\r\n*

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Instead of custom conversion, why can't use newtonsoft  (JsonConvert.SerializeObject) to convert dataset/table to JSON.

Comment: I tried newtonsoft too Same result, When I convert to xml the string is okay but json ends up looking like this. I am using .NET 4.7.2 and I tried newtonsoft version 12.0.3

Comment: Where are you seeing those backslashes? The debugger shows strings as they may appear in source code and adds escaping in the visual only. Write the text out to a file and they shouldn't be there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using a API template and trying to return a string instead of just data that's why my output was weird. Once I changed my code to the below it worked great.

```
public DataTable Get()
        {

            SqlConnection Connection;

            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            connetionString = "Data Source=" + dbIP + ";Initial Catalog=" + sqlCatalog + ";User ID=" + sqlUser + ";Password=" + sqlPassword;
            Connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString);

            SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("getAllItems '%'", Connection);
            List<string> list = new List<string>();


          Connection.Open();
            dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
            Connection.Close();

            dataSet.DataSetName = "Items";
            DataTable data = dataSet.Tables[0];


            return data;
        }
```